# Is there a safe way to map an enum variant to another with just a mutable reference to it in Rust?

Tags: rust, ownership

Consider the following code:

```rs
enum Deferred<F, T> {
  Fn(F),
  Ready(T),
}

impl<F, T> Deferred<F, T>
where
  F: FnOnce() -> T,
  T: Clone,
{
  fn get_clone(&mut self) -> T {
    let clone;
    *self = match *self {
      Self::Fn(f) => { // `f` moved here
        let data = f(); // this needs to consume `f`
        clone = data.clone();
        Self::Ready(data)
      },
      Self::Ready(data) => { // `data` moved here
        clone = data.clone();
        Self::Ready(data)
      },
    };
    
    clone
  }
}
```

The compiler complains about the `*self = match *self {...};` statement because its right hand side takes ownership of contents of `self`. Is there a way to accomplish this behaviour with just a mutable reference to `self`?

I found a workaround using `F: FnMut() -> T` so that `f` doesn't have to be moved but this approach clearly has its limitations.

I also tried what the answer to [Is there a safe way to temporarily retrieve an owned value from a mutable reference in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66597738/is-there-a-safe-way-to-temporarily-retrieve-an-owned-value-from-a-mutable-refere) suggested but it led to an issue with initialization of `clone` (the compiler could no longer reason that the match statement would initialize `clone` because the code was moved into a closure) so I had to use `MaybeUninit` with `unsafe`.

At that point it was better to read/write `self` through a raw pointer:

```rs
unsafe {
  std::ptr::write(
    self as *mut Self,
    match std::ptr::read(self as *const Self) {
      Self::Fn(f) => {
        let data = f();
        clone = data.clone();
        Self::Ready(data)
      },
      Self::Ready(data) {
        clone = data.clone();
        Self::Ready(data)
      }, 
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Additional note: Why the `clone()` at all? Both arms have owned versions of `T` to begin with, there is no need for the `clone()`. You can just `Self::Ready(f())` and `Self::Ready(data)`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this in a straightforward safe fashion, because *while `f` is being executed* there is no possible valid value of `Deferred` as defined: you don't yet have a `T` to go in `Deferred::Ready`, and you're consuming the `F` so you can't have `Deferred::Fn`.

If you use the `take_mut` crate or similar, that accomplishes this by replacing panicking with aborting, so the invalid state can never be observed. But, in your case, I would recommend introducing a third state to the enum instead — this changes the semantics but in a way that, shall we say, *respects the fact that `f` can fail.*

```rust
enum Deferred<F, T> {
    Fn(F),
    Ready(T),
    Failed,
}

impl<F, T> Deferred<F, T>
where
    F: FnOnce() -> T,
    T: Clone,
{
    fn get_clone(&mut self) -> T {
        match std::mem::replace(self, Self::Failed) {
            Self::Ready(data) => {
                let clone = data.clone();
                *self = Self::Ready(data);
                clone
            },
            Self::Fn(f) => {
                let data = f();
                *self = Self::Ready(data.clone());
                data
            }
            Self::Failed => {
                panic!("A previous call failed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this solution, the very first thing we do is swap out `*self` for `Self::Failed`, so we own the `Deferred` value and can freely move out the non-clonable `F` value. Notice that **the expression being matched is not a borrow of `self`**, so we aren't blocked from further modifying `*self`.

This particular solution does have a disadvantage: it's unnecessarily writing to `*self` on every call (which is unobservable, but could reduce performance). We can fix that, by separating the decision of what to do from doing it, but this requires writing a second pattern match to extract the value:

```rust
impl<F, T> Deferred<F, T>
where
    F: FnOnce() -> T,
    T: Clone,
{
    fn get_clone(&mut self) -> T {
        match self {
            Self::Ready(data) => {
                return data.clone();
            },
            Self::Failed => {
                panic!("A previous call failed");
            }
            Self::Fn(_) => {
                // Fall through below, relinquishing the borrow of self.
            }
        }

        match std::mem::replace(self, Self::Failed) {
            Self::Fn(f) => {
                let data = f();
                *self = Self::Ready(data.clone());
                data
            }
            _ => unreachable!()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem here is trying to take ownership of the value in the `enum` while simultaneously having a live reference (via `&mut self`) to it. Safe Rust code will not let you do that, which is the reason for the compiler error. This is also a problem with your `unsafe`-solution: What if any code inside one of the `match`-arms panics? Then the owned value created via `ptr::read` gets dropped, the stack unwinds, and the caller might catch that panic and is then perfectly capable of observing the `Deferred` it owns (of which it gave a `&mut` to `get_clone()`) after it has been dropped, that is, in an invalid state and therefor causing Undefined Behaviour (see the docs for `ptr::read` for an example).

What must be achieved therefore is to hold `&mut self` in a valid/defined state while taking ownership. You can do that by having a cheap or possibly even free variant on `Deferred`, which is put into `&mut self` *while the new value is being constructed*.

For instance:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum FooBar {
    Foo(String),
    Bar(&'static str),
}

impl FooBar {
    fn switch(&mut self) {
        // notice here
        *self = match std::mem::replace(self, FooBar::Bar("temporary")) {
            FooBar::Foo(_) => FooBar::Bar("default"),
            FooBar::Bar(s) => FooBar::Foo(s.to_owned()),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = FooBar::Bar("hello");
    s.switch();
    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

Here, we use `std::mem::replace` to switch the value behind `&mut self` with a cheaply constructed temporary value; `replace()` returns ownership of the original value, which we `match` on to construct a new value; the value returned by the `match`-expression is then put into place via the `*self`-assignment. If everything goes well, the `FooBar::Bar("temporary")` is not ever observed; but it could be observed if the `match` panicked; but even then, the code is at least safe. In case your `match` can't unwind at all, the compiler might even be able to eliminate that useless store entirely.

Coming back to your original code, I don't see how to construct a `Deferred` without `T` being `Default`, as you can neither construct the `Fn` nor the `Ready` case in a safe way. Either that can be added via an additional bound, or you can add a third variant `Empty` to your enum.

Comment: You could even make this nicer by implementing `Default` for `FooBar` and then use `std::mem::take`.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, the difference between your problem and the one that you [referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66603025/8809310) is that you also want to return the inner `T` while replacing `self`. Which is something that the there proposed crate `take_mut` does not provide. However, I noticed that it seems a bit unmaintained. So, I had a short look around, and found the [`replace_with`](https://docs.rs/replace_with/0.1.7/replace_with/index.html) crate instead. It basically does the same as `take_mut`, but it also has a [`replace_with_or_abort_and_return`](https://docs.rs/replace_with/0.1.7/replace_with/fn.replace_with_or_abort_and_return.html) function -- exactly what you need:

```rust
use replace_with::replace_with_or_abort_and_return;

impl<F, T> Deferred<F, T>
where
    F: FnOnce() -> T,
    T: Clone,
{
    fn get_clone(&mut self) -> T {
        replace_with_or_abort_and_return(self, |s| match s {
            Self::Fn(f) => {
                // `f` moved here
                let data = f(); // this needs to consume `f`
                let clone = data.clone();
                (clone, Self::Ready(data))
            }
            Self::Ready(data) => {
                // `data` moved here
                let clone = data.clone();
                (clone, Self::Ready(data))
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Tho, notice, that taking a value out of a mutable borrow, has the potential of UB that is specifically if your `f()` panics, because `self` would be left in an uninitialized state. Therefore, we get this slightly cumbersome function name, which indicates that if `f()` panic, the program will be aborted (which is the safe thing to do). However, if you expect `f()` to panic and don't want to abort the program, you can instead provide a default for `self` via the `replace_with_and_return` or `replace_with_or_default_and_return` function.